# Combining large number of meshes in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d, mesh

I imported a generated 3d model of a MRT scan into Unity. Unfortunately the model is imported into a lot of slices which make up the whole model.
The hierachy is like this:

[image]

As you can imagine it takes a lot of ressources and slows down further processes. So I want to combine the children (default_MeshPart0, default_MeshPart1, ...) of "default" into one mesh. I found out about [Mesh Combine Wizard](https://forum.unity.com/threads/mesh-combine-wizard-free-unity-tool-source-code.444483/) which works perfectly for objects with only a few children but it doesn't work with a larger number of meshes as children. I tried to move some children into another parent folder and combine them seperatly to combine the new parent folders later on but this doesn't work either as I got a random looking mesh.
Do you have an idea how to fix this or do you recommend me another process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you need to do some `post-scan process`.

Try:

- Opening the scan model in a `3d software` like Maya, 3D Max or Blender.
- `Attach` or `Merge` all the parts together.
- Export it as `.fbx`.
- Import it into Unity.
- In Unity will be a `single gameObject`.

Comment: I used Blender and added a modifier (Decimate) which did the job. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Combining the meshes is actually pretty straightforward (I'll run you through in a minute), there is a gotcha however - while its easy to do in runtime, I've had some problems trying to reliably save the resulting mesh as an hard file asset to disk. I dit get there in the end but it was trickier than it seemed. You don't need to save your asset if you are okay in this being done in Start(), and you can do it in edit mode, but the resulting mesh will not be automatically saved with the scene - just something to have in mind.

Back to geometry - geometry consists of three arrays

```
Vector3[] verts;
Vector2[] uv; 
int[] triangles;
```

The only thing to wrap your head around is that if you have n vertexes, uv[n] and vector3[n] describes n-th vertex (obviously), the triangles array is 3*n, and contains indexes refering to the vertex table, it goes in sequence, so if you want to find triangle k you read

```
x=triangles[k*3] 
y=triangles[k*3+1] 
z=triangles[k*3+2]
```

and than you have your triangle defined by three vectors verts[x],verts[y],verts[z].

There are also submeshes, used when a mesh contains multiple materials, but its not complicated once you know how the above structure is laid out.

Co create a new mesh, firs to GetComponentsInChildren, than grab a list of all the meshes, count the total vertex count j.
Create a new Mesh object, initialise it with tables verts = new int[j], tris = new int[j*3] and than just copy all the vertex data. Once you have the mesh, create a new object with a mesh filter and mesh renderer, feed the mesh with it and you're done. Problem is this will dissapear on play mode state unless you save the asset but that's a seperate question

if you have submeshes you need to list all the materials that are present and group vertieces by material used (sub group = a grup using a single material), aside from managing another list this isn't much harder (and nothing terrible happens if you ignore that step, you'll just get a single solid object) which is great for performance in most cases as your object will be a single drawcall not depending on dynamic batching)

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be problem if its created for Unity3D. Anyway If you want single mesh, you will need a 3D modeling tool to combine it then export in FBX format according to unity guideline as explained [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-exportFBX.html). I hope it helps you.